# How to set up Azure IP alias directly using DNS name?

Tags: azure, dns, ip, azure-web-app-service

I'm setting up my website on Azure service. My DNS zone is 'xxx.io' (for example). I can create address such as 'main.xxx.io' or 'web.xxx.io' using Alias record sets and they work well. But I can't access the website directly using 'xxx.io' as address. How do I achieve this?
PS: my colleague says it used to work but now it doesn't, and he doesn't know how either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a A record called `@` with the value being IP address of your website. you cant have CNAME for `@` (root domain). Well you can, but its against the rules (afaik).

Comment: I tried ```@``` but it doesn't allow me to do so, says there is already a one with ```@```.

Comment: well, what do you want me to do? delete the existing one or change it

Answer (score 1):

If your website is hosting on Azure service like virtual machines. You could just add an **A** record named **@** to point to the public IP address of Azure VM.

If your website is hosting on Azure web app service, you have to add an **A** and **TXT** type records in the DNS zone for using root domain. The app service plan(non-ASE) is multiple-tenant, you have to use TXT record to validate which website will be using the domain hostname.

The TXT record named `@`, the value is `mywebapp.azurewebsites.net`; The A record named `@`, the value is your website public IP.

You could refer to this picture and get more details [here](http://You%20could%20refer%20to%20this%20picture%20and%20get%20more%20details%20here.).
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It didn't solve the problem, but we could live with what we have right now, which is the 'web.xxx.io' domain.